# linux mint not chanign keyboard layout from persian to english

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout

i came to mint after using ubuntu for about a year. i have added persian(with persian keypad) layout to my keyboard. when i try to change from english to persian with LSuper + Space it works but not the reverse. i saw an answer somewhere to change the shortcut to alt + shift (like in windows) but im not used to that.